# Java Heap Distribution Concept Query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, memory-management

I am using below GC memory parameters :

export MEM_OPTS="-Xmx2900m -Xms2900m -XX:NewSize=786m -XX:MaxNewSize=786m -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

I am using 32 bit JVM.My server RAM is 10 GB.

From Oracle site, I got

> Why can't I get a **larger heap** with the 32-bit JVM?

The maximum theoretical **heap limit** for the 32-bit JVM is 4G. Due to various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, **in practice the limit can be much lower**. On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G. On 32-bit Solaris kernels the address space is limited to 2G. On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems.
As of Java SE 6, the Windows /3GB boot.ini feature is not supported.
If your application requires a very large heap you should use a 64-bit VM on a version of the operating system that supports 64-bit applications. See Java SE Supported System Configurations for details.

Ok.Now lets **assume** my 32 bit server can take 3.2 GB.As i know :

> ```
> -Xmx is the total heap memory
> -XX:NewSize / -XX:MaxNewSize is the range of the size of the new generation inside that heap
> the difference is the range of the size of the old generation
> -XX:PermSize / -XX:MaxPermSize is the range of the size of the permanent generation, which is the non-heap memory
> ```

According to this, 3.2 GB should not include PermSize as this is a not a heap content.Right ?

Let me know if am wrong.

I can divide 3.2 GB in Xmx and NewSize . Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NewSize is a portion of the maximum heap size. It must be smaller.

I would use the 64-bit JVM if you have Java 6 as it will make your life simpler. ;) Unless you have to use 32-bit share libraries, there is little down side.

BTW `-XX:+UseTLAB` is the default.